# Bar chart using Dates index in Python-Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

I have this type of data with Dates as index column and 3 other columns: x,y,Total

```
Date       x     y    Total

2018-12-31 4740 6477 11217 
2018-12-31 4545 6577 11277
```

I want to create a bar chart , where Dates will be x-axis and 'y' will be y-axis.
I tried this , but x-axis shows Date with time.

```
df.X.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

How can I fix it and make my chart more 'beautiful'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

As per your requirement, you first need to covert the `datetime` field to `date` field.

```
df['dateonly'] = df.index.date
```

Then, Manually pass the column names in the `x` & `y` arguments in the `plot.bar` function

```
df.plot.bar(x='dateonly',y='y')
```

Hope it solves your problem

Comment: I did that , but now x-axis is represented as integers 0-23.I want x-axis show dates , but not time.It was : 2019-01-01 00:00:00 , but I want 2019-01-01 or Jan 2019 on x-axis

Comment: @Smbat I've updated the answer, see if it tackles your problem

Comment: Thanks , it works . Can you please tell me how plot x and y columns together in bar chart

Comment: Yes sure, you can pass arbitrarily any column in the `plot.bar` function. Say for x & y columns `plot.bar(x='x', y='y')`. I'll advice you to read the official docs at: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html

Comment: how can I display tha dates  (the index of my df) on the x-axis in this format: Jan-20, instead of 20.01.2020 00:00:00 ?

Comment: @Smbat You'll have to first convert date field to the desired format using `strftime` function and then plot the column as earlier.

Comment: Error:
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: My Date is an index in my df